# I am facing following error while deploying cosum webpart

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Connections to the SharePoint server are currently disabled because the project is in Offline mode. To connect to the SharePoint server, switch to Online mode by setting the project’s Server Connection property to Online, and then try the operation again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clicking on your project and in the properties windows make sure "server Connection" says online